# Filtering polymorphic belongs_to relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism

Lets say I have these models:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable
end

class File < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true

  # How can I add an image relation?
  belongs_to :image ...
  belongs_to :file ...
end
```

What's the best way to add an image/file relations to Attachment model

And this is what I want to achieve eventually:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments, as: :attacher

  # ?
  has_many :images, 
  has_many :files
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something akin to this if my Imagelink = your Attachment, my Image = your Page, my Project = your Image, my Scenario = your File (or it's been so long, I don't remember my own code correctly).

```
class Project
  has_many :imagelinks, :as => :displayable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :images, :through => :imagelinks
end

class Scenario
  has_many :imagelinks, :as => :displayable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :images, :through => :imagelinks
end

class Unittest
  has_many :imagelinks, :as => :displayable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :images, :through => :imagelinks
end

class Imagelink
  # attributes: id, image_id, displayable_id, displayable_type
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :displayable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :project, :class_name => 'Project', :foreign_key => 'displayable_id'
  belongs_to :scenario, :class_name => 'Scenario', :foreign_key => 'displayable_id'
  belongs_to :unites, :class_name => 'Unittest', :foreign_key => 'displayable_id'
end

class Image
  has_many :imagelinks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :projects, :through => :imagelinks, :source => :project, :conditions => "imagelinks.displayable_type = 'Project'"
  has_many :scenarios, :through => :imagelinks, :source => :scenario, :conditions => "imagelinks.displayable_type = 'Scenario'"
  has_many :unittests, :through => :imagelinks, :source => :unittest, :conditions => "imagelinks.displayable_type = 'Unittest'"
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { blah blah blah }
end
```